lag and count in pyspark at each interval
data = [
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    (None, None, 1234),
    (None, None, 1234),
    (None, None, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D30", 1, 1234),
    ("D60", 2, 1234),
    ("D60", 2, 1234),
    ("D60", 2, 1234),
    ("D60", 2, 1234),
    ("D60", 2, 1234),
    ("D90", 3, 1234),
    ("D90", 3, 1234),
    ("D90", 3, 1234),
    ("D90", 3, 1234)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["segment", "cycles", "account"])

This is my dataset
Here for each segment I want to create a flag column(1/0) at the first occurrence
If I am using groupy it is merging D30 and hence giving me incorrect result
-if segment is non-consecutive then treat it as a separate group
here d30 has 2 groups
d60 and d90 have 1 group each
here is the output I want
segment|cycles|account|flag|consecutive_groups_count|
+-------+------+-------+----+------------------------+
|   null|  null|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   1|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   1|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D30|     1|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D60|     2|   1234|   1|                       4|
|    D60|     2|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D60|     2|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D60|     2|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D60|     2|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D90|     3|   1234|   1|                       4|
|    D90|     3|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D90|     3|   1234|   0|                       4|
|    D90|     3|   1234|   0|                       4|
+-------+------+-------+----+------------------------+

# Assign a flag for consecutive occurrences of segments
df = df.withColumn("flag", when((col("segment") == lag("segment").over(Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy("cycles"))) |
                                (col("segment").isNull() & lag("segment").over(Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy("cycles")).isNull()), 0)
                                .otherwise(1))






consecutive_groups_count is the sum of flag column
